# Is it a security vulnerability to expose ids of items from Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have few items in Firestore and when each of them is accessed by client in browser, I pass the id of the item from Firestore through URL parameters like `http://....?id=4ZDOiynoK25j2ikJlbZq` to access its data.

Is there any security risk even if I use some security rules for the database?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not enough information to know for sure if there is **any** security risk.  The security of any given Firestore database is generally governed by [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), not privacy of document IDs.  Always start with security rules if you're concerned about security.

If you're depending on IDs being private to only the people who have the ID, then your security rules will need to disallow queries entirely on the collection with the intended private IDs.  Keep in mind that others can still try to guess the ID, or find it someone else in your data, so it's not really 100% secure.